# Calculating total amount of time taken for a ticket in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a log table for ticket history in SQL Server 2008. here i have only datetime  and Status filed. I need to calculate total time among statuses.

**Example:**
I have opened a ticket at `2015-06-19 15:50:44.000` after sometime i have changed it to *Work in progress* at `2015-06-22 11:15:15.000`. Both time stamp values will come under the same DateTime field. I want to calculate the time difference between status changes. The status will be changed randomly.

```
ticket_number   Date & Time           Problem Status
16676       2015-06-19 15:50:14.000    Open
16676       2015-06-19 15:50:14.000    Accepted
16676       2015-06-19 15:50:44.000    Work in progress
16676       2015-06-19 16:03:13.000    Pending Vendor
16676       2015-06-22 06:32:31.000    Work in progress
16676       2015-06-22 11:15:15.000    Pending Vendor
16676       2015-06-23 10:15:15.000    Work in progress
16676       2015-06-23 10:15:15.000    Closed
```

Here i have to calculate total time from accepted to closed status and we have to exclude pending vender status time.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Edited to make the question clearer.

Comment: Which version, please? From SQL Server 2012 on, you have the `LAG` statement for such queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 2 entries for each ticket, then this is fairly straightforward. Since you didn't post any sample data or schema info we have to make some assumptions here, but for example:

```
Select   op.ticket_number
       , datediff(minute, wip.timestamp, op.timestamp) as diff_minutes
from   yourTable op
       inner join yourTable wip
           on op.ticket_number = wip.ticket_number
where  wip.status = 'Work_in_progress'
and    op.status = 'Opened'
order by op.ticket_number
```

This will take the subset of records in your table where the status is opened as "op" and another subset of your data where the status is "work in progress" as "wip". If you join those together on the ticket number you can calculate the difference in minutes (or hours, days, seconds, etc) between the 2 corresponding timestamps.
If you have more than 2 statuses to deal with this gets a bit more complex and then other methods might be more appropriate. In that case, please post some sample data and the schema of the tables involved.

Comment: **Please note:** From SQL Server 2012 on, you have the **`LAG`** statement, which does the same without doing a self-join: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: Indeed, but the title of the question states the user is using MSSQL 2008, so LAG would not be an option for him.

Comment: The tag was edited afterwards. [*SQLPolice never votes down*]

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as a separate answer as the method is quite different. Pretty sure this is what you're looking for:

```
-- Create table for sample data
Create table #tickets
(   ticket_number   int
,   dateTime_status datetime
,   ProblemStatus   nvarchar(50)
)

-- Insert sample data into temp table
Insert into #tickets
Values  (16676, '2015-06-19 15:50:14.000', 'Open')
    ,   (16676, '2015-06-19 15:50:14.000', 'Accepted')
    ,   (16676, '2015-06-19 15:50:44.000', 'Work in progress')
    ,   (16676, '2015-06-19 16:03:13.000', 'Pending Vendor')
    ,   (16676, '2015-06-22 06:32:31.000', 'Work in progress') 
    ,   (16676, '2015-06-22 11:15:15.000', 'Pending Vendor')
    ,   (16676, '2015-06-23 10:15:15.000', 'Work in progress') 
    ,   (16676, '2015-06-23 10:15:15.000', 'Closed')
    ,   (16677, '2015-06-19 15:50:14.000', 'Open')
    ,   (16677, '2015-06-20 15:50:14.000', 'Accepted')
    ,   (16677, '2015-06-20 15:50:44.000', 'Work in progress')
    ,   (16677, '2015-06-20 16:03:13.000', 'Pending Vendor')
    ,   (16677, '2015-06-23 06:32:31.000', 'Work in progress') 
    ,   (16677, '2015-06-23 11:15:15.000', 'Pending Vendor')
    ,   (16677, '2015-06-24 10:15:15.000', 'Work in progress') 
    ,   (16677, '2015-06-25 10:15:15.000', 'Closed')

-- Select time difference for status from and to per ticket
-- Time difference is measured in minutes. Change the datepare to desired unit if required.
Select      ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.ticket_number order by a.RowNum)
        ,   a.ticket_number
        ,   a.ProblemStatus as 'Status_from'
        ,   b.ProblemStatus  as 'Status_to'
        ,   DATEDIFF(MINUTE,a.dateTime_status,b.dateTime_status) as 'Time_in_minutes'
from    
        -- Nested select to set subsequent events side by side. Add row numbers.
        (Select     ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ticket_number order by dateTime_status) as 'RowNum'
                ,   ticket_number
                ,   dateTime_status
                ,   ProblemStatus
        from    #tickets) as A

        -- Join first nested query on second one with same data, but join on b.rownum = a.rownum + 1
        -- This puts the event in B next to the previous event in A
        inner join (Select  ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ticket_number order by dateTime_status) as 'RowNum'
                        ,   ticket_number
                        ,   dateTime_status
                        ,   ProblemStatus
                    from    #tickets) as B
            on a.ticket_number = b.ticket_number
            and b.RowNum = a.RowNum + 1
-- Exclude records where the beginning status is "Pending Vendor"
where   a.ProblemStatus <> 'Pending Vendor'
order by    a.ticket_number
        ,   a.RowNum

-- Drop the temp table
drop table #tickets
```

You basically still join the same data on one another as 2 separate data sets, but by adding a row number to the data you can join 1 table to the next row in the second table. This allows you to set the sequential events side-by-side, and calculate the time difference between them. Exclude any records where the ProblemStatus in the first table is "pending vendor" and you have the actual time worked on the problem. The sum of the minutes is your total time per ticket. Change the datepart to seconds if you require more accurate time measurement. This is then easily converted to a second, minute, hour format.